# How will i add dynamic HTML tag in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

[image]

I want to change this h1 HTML tag by html_tag variable. How will i do it?

```
{% set html_tag = field("html_tag") %}

<h1 class="element-headline">
    <div class="element-headline-text">
        <span class="headline-before-text">{{ before_text }}</span>
        <span class="headline-after-text">{{ after_text }}</span>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: What have u tried? What is `field`? Is it a macro, a `twig`-function, ...?

Comment: It's a twig function and it's my custom function. Where I'm taking this : http://prntscr.com/k0pgae all heading tag.

Answer (score 2):

And

```
{% set html_tag = field("html_tag") %}

<{{html_tag}} class="element-headline">
    <div class="element-headline-text">
        <span class="headline-before-text">{{ before_text }}</span>
        <span class="headline-after-text">{{ after_text }}</span>
    </div>
</{{html_tag}}>
```

doesn't work?

Comment: It's not working . it's showing syntax error : http://prntscr.com/k0pv5v

Comment: Your editor is showing a syntax error ... but does the template rendering works?

Comment: This kind of interchanging html elements isn't really pretty at all in my opinion ...

Comment: It's not working. It creating this double quotation " " in html http://prntscr.com/k0pxfw

Comment: You are sure  {{ html_tag }} is containing a valid string?

Comment: I don't know what your field function is doing. I tested it with {% set html_tag = 'b' %} and that works proper for me ... it generates <b class="element-headline"> ... </b>

Comment: Have to agree @JimPanse, it's strange to see you trying to change semantics in a webpage

Comment: Yes, double quotation showing only in my admin page but it's working font page.